# Xamarin button falling off screen

Tags: android, xamarin, button

Perhaps a "stupid" question but I could not found the answer on google or I did not know the right search terms. But how to give a button specific location for all devices even when the screen is turned on it's side.

Button on a location in the standing position.

[image: Button on a location in the standing position]

Button on a location in the sideway position.

[image]

I hope this describes what I mean.

This is the xaml code for the button:

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout Margin="600,400,10,10">
    <Button Text="Click me" Clicked="OnButtonClicked" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

I tried as well to work with `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds` and `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags`

But the same happend as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: read the docs on the different layout options.  An AbsoluteLayout is probably not the right choice if you want your UI to be relative to the screen orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Jason. If you want to use one layout to fit more screens, `AbsoluteLayout` is not a good choice.

You can put your button in the `RelativeLayout` or `FlexLayout.
Here is my code about`RelativeLayout`.

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <RelativeLayout>

        <Button  RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
             "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,
                                    Factor=0.7}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
             "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,
                                    Factor=0.8}"

                  Text="Click me" Clicked="Button_Clicked" 
                  WidthRequest="100" 
                  HeightRequest="50" 
                  HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

You should use the constraint type "relative to parent" and use factors to position the element.

Relative layout can include the control size when positioning with factors. What that means is that if you put a factor of 0, the top of the Button will be at the top of the container.

If you put a factor of 1, the bottom of the Button will be at the bottom of the container.

Likewise, a factor of 0.5 will center the center of your Button on the center of the container

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is a link about the these layouts.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/layouts#layouts-with-multiple-children

**UPDATE**

you can use `Constant` in relativelayout. Here is my code.

```
   <ContentPage.Content>
    <RelativeLayout>

        <Button  RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
             "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width,
                                    Constant=-150}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
             "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,
                                    Constant=-100}"

                  Text="Click me" Clicked="Button_Clicked" 
                  WidthRequest="100" 
                  HeightRequest="50" 
                  HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Here is running screenshot.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It does indeed work if it is the only content property. But for example if I would like to add more items to a page such as images, and label. Should this all be inside the Relative layout? Like: <RelativeLayout><StackLayout></StackLayout></RelativeLayout> because my problem was indeed that the button was inside a StackLayout what indeed did not work.

Comment: Yes, you can put the other controls(such as images or label) in the `RelativeLayout`, If you want to move the postion, you can use`RelativeLayout.XConstraint` and `RelativeLayout.YConstraint`

Comment: Thanks! One other question how is it possible that when the phone is turned the offset from the borders of the button are not the same as when the phone is in standing mode. Is here a fix for or is this not possible?

Comment: `RelativeLayout` is not `AbsoluteLayout`, all the postions are not fixed. For example, If width of my screen  is 1000px in the in standing mode, set `RelativeLayout.XConstraint` to 0.5, the X-point is 500px, when the phone is turned the offset, width of my screen is 2000px ,set `RelativeLayout.XConstraint` to 0.5, the X-point is 1000px.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this "problem" so that the width are in both cases the same? So the button is on the same place when the screen is turned?

Comment: @Xandervandenberg I update my answer. Please see my answer.

Comment: Ahhh if I understand the constant won't take in account the scaling method but only direct cordinates and fector does take it in account?